# How to fix: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'print-type' of null"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a google book search app, and before I even start I open up the inspect and I see on my console

> "Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted".

Also, just to see what other errors that come up I did a book search and the error that I am getting back says

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'print-type' of null". And the console is pointing to this line of code as the problem "this.state["print-type"]"

I'm new to react so right now I am all thumbs do I need to put a componentDidMount within my handler or will I need to further bind this handler in order for it to work?

In my constructor I have inserted `this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this)` thinking that this will solve my problem with

> "Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted."

but this did not work.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setState({
      "print-type": "all",
      filter: "ebooks"
    });
    this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);
  }

  changeFilter(e) {
    const filter = e.target.value();
    this.setState({
      filter
    });
  }

  changePrintType(e) {
    const printType = e.target.value();
    this.setState({
      "print-type": printType
    });
  }

  handleSearch(q) {
    console.log(this.state);
    const key = "AIzaSyAJ448LHnJ0N6XxzOyIRfhJFveQzwHU_Ms";
    const baseurl = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes";
    const url = `${baseurl}?q=${encodeURIComponent(q)}&key=${key}&print-type=${
      this.state["print-type"]
    }&filter=${this.state.filter}`;
    const options = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    };
```

I expect to see all books with the same title I search for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way of initialising the state is -

```
this.state = {
      print-type: "all",
      filter: "ebooks"
    };
```

The correct way of setting the state is -

```
this.setState({
      print-type: printType
    });
```

Comment: doing it like that is making  'printType' not defined

Comment: Check console.log(e.target.value) and tell

Comment: @David oh wait in your code.. Change  `e.target.value()` to `e.target.value`

Comment: Thanks, Monica the question was answered by ravibagul91

Answer (score 0):

`"Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted"` is the result of `setState()` inside `constructor()`. You need to change it to `this.state` because you're just defining your state there.

Answer (score 0):

We never write `setState` in constructor,

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setState({
      "print-type": "all",
      filter: "ebooks"
    });
    this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);
  }
```

You need to define state,

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state ={
      print_type: "all",   //never write state name like `print-type`, use underscore instead
      filter: "ebooks"
    }
    this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);
  }
```

Whenever you want to use `print_type` write like , `this.state.print_type`.

For setState,

```
this.setState({print_type:printType})
```

Comment: Never do `e.target.value()`, it's a function invocation and `e.target.value` is not a function but the value itself.